# Graphics rendering in thread game loop. Changing data on arrays

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two objects of 2D int arrays called:
originalMap and rendedMap which they contain numbers that correspond to the puzzle game map.
From the thread class i obtain the map array from the class call Puzzle.java and modifying the one.

```
   int [][] rendedMap = Puzzle.getRendedMap().getMap();
   int [][] originalMap = Puzzle.getMapObj().getMap();
```

This is my thread loop:

drawPuzzle(canvas, *map*); takes the canvas and the array and draws a map.

```
    while(running){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                    if(runSolution && movements.size()>0){                      
                        executeSolution();
                        drawPuzzle(canvas, rendedMap);
                        if(finished){//checks if the execution finished
                            runSolution=false;
                        }
                    if(message.equals("No more actions") ||
                                    message.equals("Out of bounds, try again!")){
                            System.out.println(message);
                            drawPuzzle(canvas, originalMap);
                    }
                    }else{
                        drawPuzzle(canvas, originalMap);
                    }

                    drawMovements(canvas);
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 
    }
}
```

And this is the method that i modify the array:

```
public void executeSolution(){

    numOfPlanets = 2;

    for(int x=0;x<rendedMap.length-1; x++){
        for(int y=0;y<rendedMap[x].length-1; y++){
            //Checks where the robot is and saves its initial position 
            if(rendedMap[x][y]>=7 && rendedMap[x][y]<=9){
                initX=x; initY=y; initial=true;
                System.out.println("Initial X: "+initX +" Y: "+initY );
                direction = rendedMap[x][rendedMap[x].length-1];
                System.out.println("Direction: "+direction );
            }
        }//end inner for
    }//end for

    if(movements.size()>0){
        for(int i=0; i<movements.size();i++){

            if(movements.get(i).getColour().equals("none")){
                if(movements.get(i).getMotion().equals("straight")){
                    if(direction==RIGHT){
                        if(rendedMap[initX][initY+1]==0){
                            finished=true;
                            message = "Out of bounds, try again!";
                            return;
                        }else{
                            rendedMap[initX][initY+1]= rendedMap[initX][initY+1]+6;
                            rendedMap[initX][initY]=rendedMap[initX][initY]-6;
                        }
                    }   
                }//action if
            }//color if 
        }//movements for loop

        if(numOfPlanets > 0 ){
            finished = true;

            message ="No more actions";
        }
    }//movements if statement
}
```

My problem is when i render the renderMap array for some reason originalMap changes as well and when i am trying to draw back the originalMap it doesn't change back. 
I have even print them out and checked line by line and they are the same.

Any tips what might cause this?
I spend like days to figure it out.

Comment: Do `Puzzle.getRendedMap().getMap();` and `Puzzle.getMapObj().getMap();` return the same 2d array, or are they different? It's possible that your `rendedMap` and `originalMap` arrays are referencing the same object.

Comment: actually in Puzzle class i create 2 different objects of class Map,
and i assign the same 2d array on them.
So in thread class i obtain the map array from the map objects, but in reality they have the same data on.

Comment: Then I think that's your problem. When you return the arrays by using `int [][] rendedMap = Puzzle.getRendedMap().getMap();` and `int [][] originalMap = Puzzle.getMapObj().getMap();` you aren't copying the arrays, but just referencing them. So, since they are both referencing the same array, any changes you make in one array, will affect the other. Try creating a separate 2d array for each Map object, or create a method that copies the data from the array instead of just returning a reference.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, i will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: apparently that was my problem.
I created a method which copies the array to a new array object and i render that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(direction==RIGHT) {
    if(rendedMap[initX][initY+1]==0) {
        finished=true;
        message = "Out of bounds, try again!";
        return;
    } else {
        rendedMap[initX][initY+1]= rendedMap[initX][initY+1]+6;
        rendedMap[initX][initY]=rendedMap[initX][initY]-6;
    }
}
```

check your `rendedMap` array is been initialized because this can often lead to contextual errors, especially within the android IDE.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: what? it fixed my problem and my organization, please if you have no igood information do not leave derogratory comments such as these

Comment: That comment was left prior to your edit. Before your edit you had posted some code that had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: my problem is not the rendedMap array. 
The problem is when change information on rendedMap array, it changes the originalMap array as well.

Comment: ahh jsut chec kmy new answer to see what has come thank you ok

Comment: I do not think hss answer sis correct please look my answer below it clearl the correct response

Comment: @scragglypete - please delete this answer if it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                    if(runSolution && movements.size()>0){                      
                        executeSolution();
                        drawPuzzle(canvas, rendedMap);
                        if(finished){//checks if the execution finished
                            runSolution=false;
                        }
                    if(message.equals("No more actions") ||
                                    message.equals("Out of bounds, try again!")){
                            System.out.println(message);
                            drawPuzzle(canvas, originalMap);
                    }
                    }else{
                        drawPuzzle(canvas, originalMap);
                    }

                    drawMovements(canvas);
```

recall your drawPuzzle beforte surface view is locked down as the else causes it may not be executed in that contextual loop, as I said befor it is a problem that is comon with our organization apps

hope this helps! do hesistate to ask for more assistence

sorry for english I am indian

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have checked the else condition it is reachable